# Remove redundant data?

Tags: php

**This is what I have:**

```
var places_info = [{"place_id":57,"name":"Place 1 ... }];
```

I can't use `JS` *(I need to process this data on server-side and I think node.js is a bit overkill for a single thing)* but source is all messed up and it's in `JS` format, I have no control over this.

I need to use this data in `PHP` (using `json_decode`) but it returns `NULL` if it's not proper `JSON`..

**How could I remove all the redundant data?** (`var places_info =` and `semicolon` from the end)

Comment: So you are saying you are sent that and not valid JSON... Well if the cruft is constant and known just use a few simple [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)....?  They work the same in most programming languages.

Comment: post the place_info data to a php file using ajax and json_decode

Comment: @ficuscr I need to use this data in `PHP` which means that I need to use `json_decode` but it returns `NULL` because this is not in proper `JSON` format (it has `var XX =` and `semicolon` in the end).. As far as I know, it would be a normal `JSON` if I removed all the `JS` syntax.

Comment: Yup.  I'm just really reluctant to write a simple line of code with out you having tried first.  :) Can just wait a bit and someone will I am sure.  Confirm the cruft is constant, its just the JSON data that changes?

Comment: @MawiaHL I can't, this data is constantly updating and it's coming from external URL. I need to use regexr or something similar (that I have no skills in) to remove all the `JS` syntax.

Comment: As @ficuscr said, use string functions to remove the parts you don't want from the "var XX = ...;" string and then use the `json_decode`function to process it as you want. Why use string functions first? Because that's how PHP is receiving that data.

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, only the object itself changes from time to time. As I said to MawiaHL, this data is from external URL, I have no control over it and I'll need to find a solution that takes away JS syntax on the fly. I understand the rules, that you'll need to try something first. :) I guess I'll dig into the string functions or learn regexr from 0 if PHP isn't going to do what Im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

broke me down... I tend to shy from use of `preg_` functions when not really needed.  Habit from `ereg` dark days.  To round things out I'd suggest:

```
<?php
$dirty = 'var places_info = [{"place_id":57,"name":"Place 1"}];';
$clean = substr(substr($dirty, 18), 0, -1);

var_dump(json_decode($clean));
```

The [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is one you should know.  With a few string functions you can perform many many tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't send proper JSON to PHP then this pattern should probably do it:

```
preg_match('/\[.*\]/', $string, $match);

print_r( json_decode($match[0], true) );
```